# iPad Split View App - DetailViewController Methods Never Called

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I'm using a fresh iPad split-view template application in Xcode. I've added a sample data array and the data shows up just fine in the Popover view. However, when it's tapped, it doesn't call any methods from `DetailViewController.m` (`setDetailItem` in particular) like I'd expect it to.

Am I missing something here?

(I'm not sure what code I should post for this particular question, so I'll wait on you guys to ask for it.)

Thanks SO much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot this issue, you should check the method called `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the delegate for the table view. I remember that was called `RootViewController` by default and exists in the RootViewController.m file.

It should call the `setDetailItem` method. Check if it does so.

Posting the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method body here will help better.

Comment: D'oh! That was my problem, big oversight on my part. Thank you so much!